# PHP expat parser : How to distinguish "real" [CDATA[...]] section from normal TEXT node?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to process large XML file (~1GB) in PHP using built-in XML expat parser. I set handler by calling `xml_set_character_data_handler()`, so that I can extract the TEXT data.

The problem is, the handler will be called on both "normal" TEXT node and the "real" CDATA section (for example `<![CDATA[hello world]]>`), but only the CDATA section content (i.e.:"`hello world`") will be passed to the handler.

So my question: is there any way to know whether the data passed to character data handler is a normal TEXT node, or content of `<![CDATA[...]]>` section ?

I need to know this because the XML data need to follow a strict format rule and use of `<![CDATA[...]]>` is not allowed, and I'm supposed to generate error reports for these badly formatted XML files.

P.S.: I've tried `XMLReader` but I can't get the line number of curren node, which is required for my task. I don't think it's a good idea to call `XMLReader::expand()->getLineNo()` when processing large XML files.

Comment: Although the XML specification isn't 100% prescriptive about this, there is a general consensus in the community that as the recipient of an XML document you should treat text content in exactly the same way regardless whether or not CDATA has been used. It's on the same level as requiring XML authors to write a character reference as `#x0D;` rather than `#xd;`: most XML parsers won't allow you to see which has been used, so the rule is impossible to enforce.

Comment: @MichaelKay Well many, if not most, XML parsers **DO** allow you to see which has been used. PHP built-in `XMLReader` have a nodeType constant `XMLReader::CDATA` values for !CDATA section. `libexpat` can add a callback to notify you the next node is !CDATA. And `libxml2` allows you choosing whether the `<![CDATA[` header shall be preserved or stripped. I'd be more than happy if PHP XML expat parser just pass me the value with `<![CDATA[` header attached, but I don't how to stop it from stripping out the header before passing to the handler.

Comment: Yes, there are many parsers that allow you to do this. That doesn't mean that doing it is a good idea.

Comment: @MichaelKay it may not be necessary for ordinary XML parser, since all you need is extracting values. But what I need is not an ordinary XML parser:  my task is writing a **XML Linter tool** to verify the syntax & structure of input XML file, and also check the value range of TEXT nodes. !CDATA section is not specified in the rule book of the XML file I'm dealing with, and I'm supposed to log it as a error.

Comment: CDATA to my mind is 100% equivalent to escaping special characters with ampersands, and a "rule book" that disallows it is in my view totally misguided. Such rule books should constrain the XML at a structural level (e.g. XSD or RelaxNG) not at a lexical level.

Comment: @MichaelKay well the problem is, this rule book was defined in late 1990s; probably older than many in this community. It's defined by the bureau for accepting data from providers. I'm tasked to do this after 20+ years, because recently more and more providers didn't even do unit test in house, so we're adding an extra step before submitting. The bureau system that handles this data is **Windows XP** -- yes you read it right, Windows XP on a 20 y.o. computer, and the only one who knows how to modify the codes was long gone. That's why I'm here.